# Rotating test operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

my rotate test function doesn't match the school's. Please enlighten me on where i've gone wrong. Been trying to resolve it for so long but to no avail. Thanks!

********** my Rotate test **********

Point (-50.000,-50.000) rotated 45.000 degrees is (0.000,0.000)

Point (-6.000,-6.000) rotated 45.000 degrees is (0.000,0.000)

********** School's Rotate test **********

Point (-50.000, -50.000) rotated 45.000 degrees is (0.000, -70.711)

Point (-6.000, -6.000) rotated 45.000 degrees is (0.000, -8.485)

Rotate test function:

```
   Point Point::operator%( double angle)
{
    Point p;
    double rad=angle * PI / 180.0;
    double s = sin(rad);
    double c = cos(rad);


    // rotate point
    double xnew = p.x * c - p.y * s;
    double ynew = p.x * s + p.y * c;

    p.x = xnew;
    p.y = ynew;
    return p;
    // return Point(cos(degree) * (p.x) - sin(degree) * (p.y),
              // sin(degree) * (p.x) - cos(degree) * (p.y));

    // return p;
}
```

Driver file:

```
 void RotateTest(void)
{
cout << "\n********** Rotate test ********** " << endl;

Point pt1(-50, -50);
double angle = 45;

Point pt2 = pt1 % angle;

cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
std::cout.precision(3);
cout << "Point " << pt1 << " rotated " << angle << " degrees is " << 
    pt2 << endl;

pt1 = Point(-6, -6);
angle = 45;

pt2 = pt1 % angle;
cout << "Point " << pt1 << " rotated " << angle << " degrees is " << 
    pt2 << endl;

cout << endl;
cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::fixed);
std::cout.precision(6);
 }
```

list.h file:

```
 class Point
  {
    public:
  // Point(double X, double Y);    // Constructors (2)
  explicit Point(double x, double y); 

  Point();

   double getX() const;

   double getY() const;

   Point operator+(const Point& other)const ;

   Point& operator+(double val)  ;


   Point operator*(double value) ;

   Point operator%(double angle);


   double operator-(const Point& other)const ;

   Point operator-(double val);

   Point operator^(const Point& other);

   Point& operator+=(double val);
   Point& operator+=(const Point& other) ;

   Point& operator++();
   Point operator++(int); 

   Point& operator--(); 
   Point operator--(int); 

   Point operator-() const;


        // Overloaded operators (14 member functions)
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Point 
  &point );
    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Point 
  &point );

    // Overloaded operators (2 friend functions)

  private:
  double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
  double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point

    // Helper functions
  double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) const;
  double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) const;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem I see from your posted code is that you are using a function local point, `p`, for computing the transformed point. Presumably, that is initialized to (0, 0). Rotating that point does not change its location. You need to use `this`.

```
Point Point::operator%( double angle)
{
    Point p;
    double rad=angle * PI / 180.0;
    double s = sin(rad);
    double c = cos(rad);

    // rotate point
    double xnew = this->x * c - this->y * s;
    double ynew = this->x * s + this->y * c;

    p.x = xnew;
    p.y = ynew;
    return p;
}
```

or a simplified version:

```
Point Point::operator%( double angle)
{
    double rad=angle * PI / 180.0;
    double s = sin(rad);
    double c = cos(rad);

    // rotate point
    return Point(this->x * c - this->y * s,
                 this->x * s + this->y * c);
}
```

Comment: Will tick ur comment in a few min!